# How to throw warnings in PHP?

Tags: php, undefined, warnings, code-snippets

If we miss something it's the nature that compiler producing a warning .Anyway I wanted to neglect the warning or rid from showing the warnings in php programs.

Example Warning is :

> Error(s), warning(s): PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: z in
>   source_file.php on line 11

Below is an example which shows an warning : How we can neglect or suppress the warning?

```
<?php
$x=4;
$y=3;
function func($x=3 ,$y=4)
{
    $z=$x+$y/$y+$x;
    echo '$z';
}
echo $x;
echo $y;
echo $z;
func($x,$y);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable $z has a function level scope as you declare it in a function Therefore, you are getting that warning.
Also, there is no need of defining your function as

```
function func($x=3 ,$y=4) {} // here you are limiting the function to perform calculation for only 3 and 4
```

As you are passing values to a function therefore define your function as

```
function func($x ,$y){}
```

and use that function in your code as many times as you want.

To achieve your desired result try the following code

```
$x=4;
$y=3;
function func($x=3 ,$y=4)
{
    return $x+$y/$y+$x;
}
echo $x;
echo $y;
$z = func($x,$y);
echo $z;
```

Comment: Thank You, but can you show me how to clear warnings?

Comment: you are getting that warning because you have not defined variable $z. Once you defined $z then you will not get that warning any more.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to tell you that `z` is not defined from where you are trying to use it. Actually, it is only defined within the function `func`. Review the [scope of variables in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

**Edit**: 
Q: How to clear the warning?
A: You need to either define `z` or suppress the warning from the compiler. I would **strongly** recommend that you define it. An answer below already gives a possible alternative to your code where the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank You, but can you show me how to clear warnings?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are printing $z variable at line 11, which is not defined. 
You've defined $x and $y, but no $z.

The $z in your "func" function exists in a scope of the function only and not the "main" script.

So, I guess is what you trying to do:

```
<?php

function func($x=3 ,$y=4)
{
    $z=$x+$y/$y+$x;
    return $z;
}

$x=4;
$y=3;

//Now $z is defined!
$z = func($x,$y);

echo $z;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

becouse you have not defined $z. correct code is given below.

```html
<?php
 $x=4;
 $y=3;
 $z="";
 function func($x=3 ,$y=4){
     $z=$x+$y/$y+$x;
     echo $z;
 }
 echo $x;
 echo $y;
 echo $z;
 func($x,$y);
?>
```

Comment: Thank You, but can you show me how to clear warnings?